# Default Scope on Sharepoint Advanced Search

Tags: sharepoint, search, advanced-search

Is there any way to automatically select a specific scope on Sharepoint advanced search interface without having to select the search box via Javascript?

I found [this hint](http://blogs.msdn.com/mattbremer/archive/2009/08/17/set-particular-scope-for-advanced-search-box-web-part-without-using-scopes-list.aspx), but I couldn't find the XML file he's talking about anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML he talks about on the link is located at:

Advanced Search Page => Edit Page => Modify Shared WebPart (the Advanced Search Form WebPart) => (Properties Group) => Properties field.

It starts with `<root xmlns:...`